# deduce open mapping theorem from Banach's homomorphism theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

We have been given this question in our homework, and I really just don't have an idea where to start

Use the canonical factorisation to deduce the Open Mapping Theorem from Banach's Homomorphism Theorem.

I don't know where to get a bijective bounded linear operator in order to make use of Banach's Homomorphism Theorem?  Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Where to get? From *the canonical factorisation*.